# A scalable function for get boundary vertices in a graph

Tags: python, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

Given a community division I need a list of vertices that have edges in more than one community, i.e., boundary vertices.

I've tried this:

```
import igraph
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = igraph.Nexus.get("condmatcollab2005")

    tic = time.clock()
    cl = g.community_fastgreedy()
    membership = cl.as_clustering().membership
    print "community time: "+str(time.clock() - tic)

    # --> Do I need to leave this part more faster =======
    tic = time.clock()
    boundary = []
    visited = set()
    for vertex in g.vs():
        if vertex.index in visited: continue
        for neighbor in g.neighbors(vertex.index):
            if membership[vertex.index] != membership[neighbor]:
                boundary.append(vertex.index)
                visited.add(vertex.index)
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    boundary.append(neighbor)
                    visited.add(neighbor)
                break
    print "boundary time: "+str(time.clock() - tic)
```

This implementation is very slow. I don't if there is a faster way or more cleaner to do this.

E.g., maybe there is a faster way by using the `cl.as_clustering()` object or other data structure more efficient.

I need some help with how to optimize my code! Do I need to leave my code more faster.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Asking for "suggestions to improve my code" are not well-suited for this site.

Comment: @Hooked I need some help with how to optimize my code. Do I need to leave my code more faster.

Comment: Perhaps have a gander at the Code Review site, this question *may* be on-topic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VertexClustering` object returned by `cl.as_clustering()` has a `crossing()` method - this gives you a Boolean vector which contains `True` for edges that are between clusters and `False` for edges that are within a cluster. You can easily extract the indices of the crossing edges like this:

```
cl = g.community_fastgreedy().as_clustering()
crossing_edges = [index for index, is_crossing in enumerate(cl.crossing()) if is_crossing]
```

Then you can simply take each edge and put its endpoints in a set:

```
boundary = set()
for edge in g.es[crossing_edges]:
    boundary.update(edge.tuple)
```